# Git with artifactory

Tags: git, version-control, npm, bower, artifactory

Just finished setting up Artifactory for NPM and Bower and it was amazingly easy to use. You could just change the repository URL's and everything just worked.

Looking at the documentation on how to get Artifactory to work with github vcs it looks overly complicated. I am wondering if anyone has seen a way to setup git to work with Artifactory?

The [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/VCS+Repositories) I found just uses curl, which doesn't allow me to use git in the future.

If not has anyone written any hooks that transfigure the syntax required by Artifactory to something git can pass along and use.  Don't want to lose the ability to use basic git clone, git pull functionality.

Answer (score 9):

There are two ways to integrate Git with Artifactory:

- Use Artifactory interface (REST or UI or whatever) to get artifacts, proxied from Git
- Use Git interface to work with artifacts in Artifactory.

The latter is not implemented yet.

---

<sup>I am with [JFrog](http://jfrog.com), the company behind [Bintray](https://bintray.com/) and [[artifactory]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/artifactory), see [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402053/jbaruch) for details and links.</sup>

Comment: Any hope of implementing the latter?

Comment: We will implement Git client support, for sure, but only [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/) client (since we're binary repository, after all).

Comment: @zmanc - Artifactory LFS support is available in  version [3.9](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+3.9)

Comment: 8 years later, have `git clone`, `git pull`, etc. been implemented yet?