# Clone github.com repo through Artifactory git mirroring

Tags: github, artifactory

Artifactory supports `vcs` repositories with native support for github, bitbucket and other git servers.

Their documentation shows that a github.com mirror can be setup and accessed through the API

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/VCS+Repositories

```
curl -iL  "http://artifactory.example.com/api/vcs/downloadBranch/github-vcs/jquery/jquery/main"
```

**How would you perform the same clone operation using the `git` cli and not `curl ?**

---

#### Attempts

```
git clone "http://artifactory.example.com/api/vcs/downloadBranch/github-vcs/vim/vim/master
git clone https://artifactory.example.com/vim/vim
git clone https://artifactory.example.com/api/vcs/github-vcs/vim/vim
```

Answer (score 2):

Per the docs and open issues, at this moment Artifactory is supporting vcs (git) clone only with REST API's and not with git client (But supports [git-lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/)).
You can find more details here [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30103030/git-with-artifactory)
Also there is open [issue](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-23490) in artifactory jira